# Limit text when output richtext

Tags: richtext

I have a rich text output section I want to limit to specific number of characters or words. So user able preview the blog post and link to the full blog. I try  `entry.body|slice(0, 100) ~ '...'`. But it slice of my html tag and display html code in front end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a plugin to solve this.

Which is use this plugin.
https://github.com/ehousestudio/craft_hacksaw

Answer (score 18):

No need for a plugin, just use twig's `slice` filter, combined with the `striptags` filter.

I've thrown in the `default` filter for good measure, in case the body is empty for some reason.

```
{{ entry.body|striptags|slice(0,100)|default('Read more') }}...
```

`slice` will simply output the first 100 characters (starting at `0` the first character), including spaces into the template. `striptags` ensures that no html tags will be output.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can extend twig with extensions. I have not tried this, but I found this extension which preserves HTML.

https://www.versioneye.com/php/dzango:twig-truncate-extension/1.0.8

I think you have to create a plugin to use it. A fast way is to follow by example on this one perhaps: https://github.com/lukeholder/craft-inflect

Comment: I use this plugin.https://github.com/ehousestudio/craft_hacksaw

Comment: Looks pretty good!

Answer (score 2):

For my future self:

This is my solution now in Craft CMS 3 and 4.

```
{{ 'Hello world'|truncate(10) }}
{# Output: Hello… #}
```

An ellipsis (…) will be appended to the string if it needs to be truncated, by default. You can customize what gets appended by passing a second argument. (Note that a longer appended string could result in more of the original string getting truncated.)

More configs available too:
https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/filters.html#truncate