# Get excerpt of entry from search query

Tags: entries, search

If I enter a query into the search bar I would like to see an excerpt (let's say 140 characters) of each entry that is related to the query.

Here is what I use on the search result page to display the results.

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).order('score') %}

{% if entries|length %}
<p>{{ entries|length }} results:</p>

<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>Your search for “{{ query }}” didn’t return any results.</p>
{% endif %}
```

How do I add entry excerpts like: https://craftcms.com/search?q=entry

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [`slice`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) filter. To return 140 characters max. you would do something like this:

```
{% if entry.body %}
    {{ entry.body|slice(0, 140) }}
{% endif %}
```

See [this other question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/4361/125) on a similar topic if you want to apply this on a rich text field. Because this solution only works with plain text.

Comment: This thew an exception for me. `Calling unknown method: craft\elements\Entry::body()` I am using craft 3

Comment: Is that your field handle, `body`?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the Happy Lager demo site there's a Short Description field, which functions as an excerpt for indexes and search results. I imagine P&T use something similar for the Craft docs.

You could also force your results onto one line and trim it with css, which is how P&T do it on the Craft docs search results page:

```
li { overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I use [Trimmer](https://github.com/rkingon/Craft-Plugin--Trimmer) for this, it's pretty much the only plugin I use these days.

I don't know for sure, but I suspect P&T may use an 'excerpt' field to store a short sentence for use on the search results page, rather than cropping from longer copy.

Comment: Do I understand it right and this does remove all HTML tags? Again a deal breaker for rich text fields but otherwise a great little plugin. I especially like the option to trim before full words only.

Comment: Yes, it does strip HTML. There was a plugin for EE that would allow HTML and close any tags left open after trimming, I must try and find it to see if it can be/has been ported.

Comment: I added pull request for option to keep html tags [github](https://github.com/rkingon/Craft-Plugin--Trimmer/pull/7)